# Rust: Convenience syntax for specifying types on trait implementations?

Tags: generics, rust, traits

Consider the following code with a struct `S` with a constrained generic type parameter `Idx` and a default value for `Idx`.

```
use num::{PrimInt, Unsigned};

struct S<Idx = u32>
where
    Idx: Unsigned + PrimInt, {
    // ... Some fields
}

impl<Idx: Unsigned + PrimInt> Clone for S<Idx> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        S {}
    }
}

impl<Idx: Unsigned + PrimInt> Eq for S<Idx> {
    fn eq(&self, rhs: &Self) -> bool {
        true
    }
}
```

I would like to implement a bunch of traits for `S`, but I find always specifying the constraints for the `Idx` type parameter tedious. If I don't specify `Idx` on a trait implementation, the code compiles but only has an implementation for `Idx = u32`.

Is there some convenience syntax where I don't have to specify the `Idx: Unsigned + PrimInt` all the time but still correctly implements the traits?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a syntax built in, but you can make one yourself using macros:

```
macro_rules! s_impl {
    ( $($t:path => $i:tt)+ ) => {
        $(impl<Idx: Unsigned + PrimInt> $t for S<Idx> $i)+
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
s_impl!(
    Clone => {
        fn clone(&self) -> Self {
            S {}
        }
    }
    PartialEq => {
        fn eq(&self, rhs: &Self) -> bool {
            true
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @cdhowie is correct, but I would like to point that there is an accepted (but not yet implemented, as of time of writing) RFC to allow you to omit such bounds - [RFC #2089 Implied Bounds](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2089-implied-bounds.html).

It is not yet clear what will be the form of the feature, though, because it is a [semver hazard](https://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2022/04/12/implied-bounds-and-perfect-derive/).