# Implement a struct regardless of what a generic type is, without a lot of repetitive code

Tags: generics, rust

This struct holds a field that needs to have a lot of different traits.

```
struct ManyRequirements<T> 
    where
        T:Ord,
        T:Copy,
        T:Clone,
        T:Iterator,
        T:Display
{
    something: T
}
```

I want to write methods for it that work regardless of T, like a "new" method for example. I just want to be able to say ManyRequirements::new() and have it work properly. But if I tried,

```
impl ManyRequirements {
    fn new() {

    }
}
```

or

```
impl<T> ManyRequirements<T> {
    fn new() {

    }
}
```

I get

```
the trait bound `T: Ord` is not satisfied
the trait `Ord` is not implemented for `T`
```

repeated for each trait T failed to be implemented for. The only thing that works is

```
impl <T> ManyRequirements<T> 
    where
        T:Ord,
        T:Copy,
        T:Clone,
        T:Iterator,
        T:Display
{

}
```

Is there a shorter way to say "T can be whatever"? Something like

```
impl <_> ManyRequirements<_> 
{

}
```

Comment: But `T` _can't_ be whatever, since `ManyRequirements` requires it to implement those traits. If it actually doesn't, you code omit the where clause on `ManyRequirements`'s definition and only include the traits constraints on the impl block that need them

Comment: Also that is one of the reasons trait constraints are usually on `impl` blocks rather than on structures. And you can use `+` to constraint types on multiple traits rather than repeating `T:` every time e.g. `impl <T> ManyRequirements<T> where T: Ord + Copy + Clone + Iterator + Display`. Or just put the relevant traits on the impls where they are needed e.g. none of these traits is useful to create a `ManyRequirements` (possibly aside from `Copy`), however `Default` might be if the ctor is parameter-less.

Comment: @Brian61354270 but why does Rust require me to specifically say in the impl that the struct's generic has to implement all of those traits, when it already knows this since I declared it in the struct declaration? Is there a way to have multiple impl blocks that all require T to implement those traits without a lot of repeated code?

Comment: should clarify: I'm trying to use the type state pattern like in [this video](https://youtu.be/_ccDqRTx-JU) but I want my struct to also have a variable that implements some specific traits. For this pattern, you have to make multiple impl blocks, but I want each block to have the same requirements for what that one generic type should implement. Do I have to repeat that the type needs to implement those traits in each block or is there a way to do it without repitition?

Comment: This feature is stalled here: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44491. [dhardy suggests](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44491#issuecomment-1088375079) using [`impl_tools::impl_scope!`](https://crates.io/crates/impl-tools#impl-scope).

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57262540/5445670, https://stackoverflow.com/q/49434716/5445670, https://stackoverflow.com/q/49229332/5445670, https://stackoverflow.com/q/72753654/5445670

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should trait bounds be duplicated in struct and impl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49229332/should-trait-bounds-be-duplicated-in-struct-and-impl)

Comment: @SolomonUcko those answer my question, thank you! is there a way to mark the question as answered by you or something like that

Comment: @JayMehta You're welcome, thanks! I've now added an answer, so you can click the checkmark and possibly the upvote button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is stalled here: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44491. [dhardy suggests](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44491#issuecomment-1088375079) using [impl_tools::impl_scope!](https://crates.io/crates/impl-tools#impl-scope).

Duplicate of:

- [Why do I need to repeat my generic type constraint when implementing a trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57262540/5445670)
- [Why is it necessary to add redundant trait bounds even though my trait uses those same traits as bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49434716/5445670)
- [Should trait bounds be duplicated in struct and impl?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49229332/5445670)
- [Rust: Convenience syntax for specifying types on trait implementations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72753654/5445670)